# How can i use the bitbucket rest api to get all the repos using springboot?

Tags: java, bitbucket

How can I use the bitbucket rest API to get all the repos in java?

How can I do it using spring boot?

Can anybody provide me with an example of it?

Comment: Are you asking about Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket server

Answer (score 0):

**For fetching repositories list:**

You can use this endpoint [BitBucket Repositories API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories)

**For repository cloning:**

You can use [jGit library for this](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/).

All you have to do is setup auth for BitBucket server (Create SSH key and use it with library).

Or you can directly use commands with Java Process API (java/lang/Process).

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git clone ...your repos...");
```

Comment: i want to connect through java program using rest calls. in pom.xml what are the dependencies i should add?

Comment: I guess Bitbucket doesn't have java-client for that. So, you have to implement this functionality by yourself. You can use `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` for that.

Comment: Minor note: the API link there is for Bitbucket Cloud, but OP is asking about Bitbucket Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UniRest](http://unirest.io/java.html) for this. Sample code to get all the repos of a user with name `John` is like this.

```
HttpResponse<String> response = 
Unirest.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/John")
.header("authorization", "Bearer  <token>")
.header("content-type", "application/json")
.header("accept", "application/json")
.asString();
```

Note : This is for BitBucket cloud. You can do the same for bitbucket server using the corresponding url.